# Value of [a b c] from (a×(b×c)).(a×c)?

Tags: vectors, cross-product

If a and c are unit vectors at an angle $\pi/3$ with each other and (a×(b×c)).(a×c)=5, then what is the value of [a b c]? I just know the basic meaning of what are vector and scalar triple product. How do I do this question? I have to do it in about two minutes. Would someone please help?

Comment: For those like me who had to look it up, the scalar triple product of three vectors is the signed volume of the parallelepiped spanned by the vectors, i.e. the determinant. I don't know what else I expected, but there it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We want to compute $a\cdot b\times c=-b\cdot a\times c$. We'll use $a\times (b\times c)=(a\cdot c)b-(a\cdot b)c$ so $$5=(a\times (b\times c))\cdot (a\times c)=(a\cdot c)(b\cdot a\times c).$$Hence $$[a b c]=\frac{-5}{a\cdot c}=\frac{-5}{\cos\frac{\pi}{3}}=-10.$$

Answer (score 1):

Use $a\times(b\times c)=(a\cdot c)b-(a\cdot b) c$.
Then
$$(a\times(b\times c))\cdot(a\times c)=(a\cdot c)b\cdot(a\times c)-(a\cdot b)c\cdot(a\times c)=-(a\cdot b)[a,b,c]$$
etc.